# How to find largest element value in array according to following code segment

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int max, n[]={50,30};

    int arrayLength = sizeof(n)/sizeof(int);
    cout << "Length is"<< arrayLength<<endl;


 for(int x=0; x<arrayLength; x++)
 {

    if (n[x]>n[x+1])
        max = n[x];
    else
        max = n[x+1];   
 }

  cout << "Max is : " << max;
```

how to find max in array

Comment: Did you search?  There are a plethora of examples on StackOverflow and the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element):

```
max = *std::max_element(n, n+arrayLength);
```

Comment: Just make sure `arrayLength` is > 0, otherwise dereferencing the return value is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can code up brute-force

```
int array_max = -1; // Or some very negative number.
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i)
{
  if (n[i] > array_max)
  {
    array_max = n[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Unless negative values are valid entries in the array, in which case use a pointer instead: `int *array_max = NULL; for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) { if ((!array_max) || (n[i] > *array_max)) { array_max = & n[i]; } }`

Comment: Thank you very much